# I get no text in the body of the email when I try to share content using an HTC Thunderbolt running Android 2.3.4

Tags: cordova, htc-thunderbolt

I get no text in the body of the email when I try to share content.

- I am using an HTC Thunderbolt running Android 2.3.4.
- However, I do not get this problem in Samsung phone.

I have done programming of the application though `Phonegap`. Are there any settings which need to be changed so that I can share the content of the page through email (while using HTC)?